# Get Item from a ListView

Tags: android, listview

My app is displaying 3 String with 3 **Text-view** in a **list-view**.

My Problem is that I create on layout for my **list-view** and i am not able to get the item from the first text view in the **onListItemClick** method.

How can I achieve achievement this?

Layout of the ListView:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/outputlayout"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:background="@color/ligthgrey">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txOutputDeparture"
        android:layout_width="130dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Abfahrt "
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:maxLength="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txOutputDuration"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/txOutputDeparture"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Dauer"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txOutputTransition"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/txOutputDuration"
        android:text="Umstieg"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Method where i create and fill the listView and its and ListActivity

```
 public void getRoute() {

        mdbH = new DatabaseHelperActivity(this);
        cursor = mdbH.fetchallRoutes(intent.getStringExtra("StartHaltestelle"),intent.getStringExtra("ZielHaltestelle"), intent.getStringExtra("Zeit"));
        ArrayList<DefineRouteActivity> route = new ArrayList<DefineRouteActivity>();
        while(cursor.moveToNext()) {
              route.add(new DefineRouteActivity(cursor.getString(0),cursor.getString(2),cursor.getString(4)));
        }

        ArrayAdapter<DefineRouteActivity> adapter = new RouteAdapterActivity(this, route);

        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

AdapterActivity:

```
Activity context;
    ArrayList<DefineRouteActivity> arraylist;

public RouteAdapterActivity(Activity context, ArrayList list) {
    super(context,R.layout.outputlayout,list);
    this.context = context;
    arraylist = list;
}
@Override
public int getCount() {

    return arraylist.size();
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View contentview, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

        DefineRouteActivity routeItems = arraylist.get(position);
        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.outputlayout,null);

        TextView tvDeparture = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txOutputDeparture);
        tvDeparture.setText(routeItems.getAbfahrtszeit());
        TextView tvDuration = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txOutputDuration);
        tvDuration.setText(routeItems.getDauer());
        TextView tvTransition = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txOutputTransition);
        tvTransition.setText(routeItems.getUmstieg());

        return view;


    }
```

Here is my onClick Method:

```
@Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

        ((View)v).
        Intent detail = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),DetailOutputActivity.class);
        detail.putExtra("StartStop",l.getItemAtPosition(0).toString());
        detail.putExtra("EndStop","ich");
        detail.putExtra("Time","du");
        detail.putExtra("Route","er");

        startActivity(detail);
    }
```

Here is my Layout containing the listView:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


        <ListView
            android:id="@id/android:list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"></ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: show your code please...

Comment: without looking into your try/code, no one help you out.

Comment: Check this example: http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial.aspx?tid=1351248

Comment: How can we help you without code? There is a much resource available on Google but without showing code not possible.

Comment: sry i added the code..

Answer (score 0):

You need another xml containing the listView.

For example: sample.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >



    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lv1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


</LinearLayout>


</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

In your mainActivity.java:

```
    setContentView(R.layout.sample.xml);
    lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lv1);
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(this);
```

Comment: But i have a listActivity. Is it not possible with this Activity to get the items?

Comment: my listid is "android:list". I think i can access with the setonItemClickListener to the view which was clicked. But who should the code look like?

Comment: My mainActivity.java is your listActiviy.

Comment: yeah i actually did this but how should the onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) look like to get every single item?

Comment: please look above i edited my question... at the bottom is my onclick method and i need to get the string name..

Answer (score 0):

Your listActivity  must implement OnItemClickListener.

Then implements onItemClick method. Example:

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    int id_object = ((object)a.getAdapter().getItem(position)).getIdInstalacion();

    Intent i = new Intent(this, Other.class);
    i.putExtra("id_", id_object);
    startActivity(i);


}
```

Comment: when my id of the listview is like @id/android:list how can i implement onItemClickListener?

Comment: Please put your ListActivity code and your all XML containing the listView